# Linked questions with high votes looks strange

Tags: bug, design

Look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175859/tailormade-table-of-contents-showcase at the right handside the linked questions are listed together with votes it seems. However for big numbers something strange is going on:

[image]

Comment: It looks fine here. Are you sure your page is not zoomed in? Because I have much smaller font there. As well, please add which browser you use, in which version, and in which OS.

Comment: two-line vote count confirmed here.  firefox 26.0 on windows.  also with internet explorer 9.0.8112.16421 (update version 9.0.25) and with seamonkey 2.23.